# What is the different between PHP-SDK Application access token and Application Access token that generated with oauth/access_token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

The new Facebook PHP-SDK have a getApplicationAccessToken method, which is the join between your [appID]|[appSecret].
I usually use a request from graph with this url https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token and turn out have a different value from the first.
Both access token can access the app detail by using this request
https://graph.facebook.com/[appID]

So which one should be use???, its confuse me, I would rather to use the first one, bcoz it doesnt have to make a graph request but can I do that or should I???

Comment: Of course you can use the first version, `app_id|app_secret`. Since internally the PHP SDK creates the app access token the same way, I think its safe to say that this will always work.

Comment: Sorry, but what do u mean with "the same way", the app access token that generated from graph is totally different with the one from PHP-SDK, I don't know which one more consistent :(

Comment: @CBroe is right, the token you get from [https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token) is actually [User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) which is deemed to be different. If you want access data accessible publicly or by your app only then you don't require the same as access to graph.facebook.com/appID doesn;t requires [any token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/).